# Perl is there a way to reexport the imported variables

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Is there a way to re-export the variables that are imported from another module.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean. What is it you want to do?

Comment: @Borodin in my module 1 I am exporting some global variable. Module 2 uses module 1. I want to re-export the module 1 global variables from module 2, so in my Perl script i can use them. My Perl script uses module 2. I can always access them in my perl script like Module1->variable. But I want to know if i can access directly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just like any other package variables.

```
use Module qw( $Var );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $Var );
use Exporter qw( import );
```